# cs2cs outputs inverted X,Y for EPSG 2451

Tags: cs2cs

I am trying to convert some coordinates from EPSG 4326 to EPSG 2451
The inputs are: Lat  35.33465507 Long 139.68581968

According to
https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=2451&x=139.6858197&y=35.3346551
The outputs are  X -13409.859087353543, Y -73804.55015077966

However when I put the data into cs2cs X and Y appear to be inverted, the man page says the default output is X,Y (I can invert with -s argument)
https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cs2cs/

Example:
C:\OSGeo4W>echo 35.33465507 139.68581968 0 | cs2cs EPSG:4326 EPSG:2451

-73804.55       -13409.86 0.00

Is there something I am doing wrong here, I am pretty new to this. I did check the WKT string on espg.io and it doesn't seem to mention transposing the axis.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to GIS.SE! Axis order is in OGC WKT2. X is Northing, _cs2cs_ output seems to be ok.

Answer (score 3):

The coordinate axis order of EPSG:2451 in the official EPSG database is northing-easting

https://epsg.org/crs_2451/JGD2000-Japan-Plane-Rectangular-CS-IX.html?

There is also this paragraph in the cs2cs documentation https://proj-tmp.readthedocs.io/en/master/apps/cs2cs.html

> When using a WKT definition or a AUTHORITY:CODE, the axis order of the
> CRS will be enforced. So for example if using EPSG:4326, the first
> value expected (or returned) will be a latitude.

You have used the AUTHORITY:CODE definition for both input and output, and like you correctly used the latitude-longitude order for input, cs2cs returns the result in northing-easting order that it the axis order of EPSG:2451.

The documentation may not be most exact with axis order behavior but you can improve the documentation in GitHub through a link https://github.com/mwtoews/PROJ/edit/master/docs/source/apps/cs2cs.rst

The transformations in the epsg.io site uses the so called "traditional GIS order" that means longitude-latitude or easting-northing always and both for input and output. Many other utilities do the same, for example gdaltransform https://gdal.org/programs/gdaltransform.html.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at this on [epsg.org:](https://epsg.org/crs_2451/JGD2000-Japan-Plane-Rectangular-CS-IX.html)

[image]

Northings are "X" and Eastings are "Y"? I checked a couple of other projected systems and they are vice-versa, which is what I'd expect:

[image]

I think that explains what you are seeing. Is it defined that way because maps are conventionally printed east-up in that coordinate system? Don't know.

But I think you need to know this in order to get the coordinates the "right" way round. `cs2cs` is returning coordinates in the order of the "order" column and its up to you to interpret them as X and Y "correctly" (which is up to you, maybe you want East up)...

Comment: Axis abbreviations are just names and one should not expect anything else about the meaning of X and Y. For example also in this system the first coordinate is northing and called X and second coordinate is easting and called Y https://epsg.org/crs_2430/Beijing-1954-3-degree-Gauss-Kruger-CM-99E.html? I suppose that applies to all Gauss-Krüger systems worldwide but I an not sure. Nothing to to with east-up map orientation.